# Is it possible to use a string to reference a json object within an Ajax statement?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

So i have a javascript function. It performs one ajax call, to retrieve a json object full of data. Within the success function of that ajax call i perfrom ANOTHER ajax call to retrieve the names of the columns of data for that particular set. (yes i'm sure there's a better way but thats not my issue). At this point in time i have two variables: items(json array) and interfaceCols(just an array of strings). Then i try to create an html string to create a table with said data.

Here is my code which will make everything more clear:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"/ryan/nonEmber/ajax.php?table=Interfaces",
                    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest){},
                    success: function(data, textStatus) {
                    interfaceCols = data.split(" ");
                    $.getJSON("/ryan/nonEmber/getJson.php?table=Interfaces", function( data ){
                        var items = [];
                         $.each(data.post, function(key, val){
                            items.push(val);
                          });
                        for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                            var myString = '<tr id = "visibleRow">';
                            console.log(items[i].interfaceCols[4]);
                            for(j = 0; j < interfaceCols.length; j++){                              
                                myString = myString + '<td id = "visibleDef">' + items[i].interfaceCols[j] +'</td>';
                            }
                            myString = myString + '</tr>';
                            interfaces.push(myString);
                        }

                     });                    
                     }
    });
```

My javascript file throws an error on the `"myString = myString + '<td id ='...` line.

I am almost positive that it is because i'm just placing a string at the end of `"items[i]"` with `".interfaceCols[j]"`

Can anybody suggest a way to do this? The whole point is so that i dont have to manually type out every column name, because i have alot of tables and each table has many columns.

Comment: What is the error? What does the JSON look like?

Comment: Is `post` an Object property of your `data` Object, and an Array, returned in `$.getJSON('url.json', function(here){/* use here */});`?

Comment: `console.log(items)` after the `$.each()` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a JS object `s`:

```
s = {a: 1, b: 2}
```

You have (at least) two options to access an attribute:

```
s.a // returns 1
```

Which seems to be what you are trying to do right now. To access it with a dynamic name, you can use:

```
s['a'] // returns 1
```

In your case, it should be:

```
items[i][interfaceCols[4]]
```